# Pragmatic approach for securing sensitive data in PHP/MySQL app?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a form on my site that collects some fairly sensitive data (personally identifying data). I have been reading on here how best to secure and am somewhat overwhelmed by the varying opinions. First, let me explain what I have done so far:

- My site is a joomla 3.x site, and for retrieving any form data it is done with a built in class that does some input validation (i.e. I am not just taking raw GET or POST data).
- My site does not have user registration. There is just a superuser account, and I am the only admin.
- I have a shared web host and can't really speak to their internal measures.
- I set up the form so that it is done via https.
- In PHP config I make sure magic quotes is on.
- When doing db queries, Joomla uses a built in class that escapes strings (so I think the site is at least somewhat resistant to SQL injection).
- For all form fields I limit the varchar length to reasonable values.

So far, the data is stored in the DB as plain text, and this is what I want to change. I read about MySQL's built in AES function and BLOBs, but I read on here that a lot of people recommend against it (though others think it is fine...). I know the ultimate approach is probably using keys externally stored elsewhere, but I am also trying to keep things as simple as possible, while being sufficiently secure. If I am taking other measures to safeguard (as mentioned above) will the MySQL functions give me a decent level of security?

Also, when a user submits the form, they receive an email with their data. I confirmed that the email seems somewhat secure in that the header shows

```
Received: from myhost (myhost. [IP])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id
    br2si8908071ojb.205.2015.04.22.08.36.02
    for <someemail>
    (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
```

Anyway, before I start implementing some sort of secure storage in the db, I was curious what you all recommend as a nice pragmatic approach.

Comment: Magic quotes were removed in PHP 5.4. You should upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: "magic quotes on"?! You should [read the comment in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php), and then you should leave the past and join us here in the present... we have cookies.

Comment: "seems somwhat secure" - because the hop from your local MTA to Google used SSMTP? You have some very funny ideas about security, some glaring gaffs (magic quotes) and are very optimistic about our ability to identify and fix them based on the information supplied here (not to mention the suitability of this forum for such a question).

Comment: Ahhh yes, my web host is on 5.4, so that is good to know! But my post is more about the storage question. Regards,Brian

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot depends on your use case.  What do you need to do with this data later?  I would definitely encrypt and salt data before inserting it to the database, I would try to make sure that no other part of your app can be easily hacked with SQL injection (lookup Joomla hacks, is it possible?) and the such, and I would review how the admin login is made to make sure it couldn't be a vector for attacks.

A bigger problem that I see is that sending this "sensitive" data via unencrypted e-mail might just about eliminate all other attempts at securing it.  I think the header you're showing is only about your connection to the SMTP server, but there this content will linger on Google's servers forever, it will be sent to a possibly less secure destination server, and it may be retrieved using an unencrypted connection.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

First, don't use magic quotes; especially if you're already escaping values with a built-in class. This will lead to potentially double-escaped input, which is bad. Furthermore, magic quotes are generally not considered secure (because they're magic). Source: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php. From the manual:

```
"Warning This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0."
```

Second, you'll want to ecnrypt data that you want to see again. Examples of this would be names, dates, credit card numbers.

What you don't want to see again, hash. By that I mean if you only need to compare data and not read it like in the case of a password, use SHA256 (or better) to mathemtically remove the possibility for the data to be reversed.

As for salting (which another answer mentioned) this refers to the practice of adding a random string into the encryption or hashing to avoid an attack known as a rainbow table. This process looks like this (pseudocode)

```
var salt = "9285gh8927thg0nfc30897gnvh2087vgh 8g7v2n";
var data = "sensitive data";

var encrypted_data = encrypt(data + salt);
```

As for data filtering, you'll want to do more than just deal with SQL injection (though that's a good start). You'll also want to take a look at XSS (OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)

Also, as an aside; you should have database users that only have permission to do one sort of action (ie: a user for writing to the database, and a user for reading from the database).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. All the data has to be seen again so I will go with the approach you outline. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: You can mark this as the best answer if you like it ^^

Comment: I tried to vote for it but my account is too new as I learned